# Android init.rc's statements for changing surfaceflinger's gid

Tags: android, system, init, surfaceflinger

In android filesystem, a init.rc script has statements to change or append user and groups for surfaceflinger like below.

```
    service surfaceflinger /system/bin/surfaceflinger
            class main
            user system
            group graphics drmrpc
            onrestart restart zygote
```

By the way, interesting thing is that user is system, but group does not have system.
As above script, there are only graphics and drmrpc for group.

Why system group is not set ?

If i set the system group for some reasons. Does it compromise something ?